# Primefaces fileUpload js API

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces library in my application. I need change users picture on click by image. Can I hide primefaces file uploader component and work with it with javascript? I.E. can I use it from javascript like in following code?

```
fileUploader.openFile();
fileUploader.sendFile();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose a file:

```
fileUploader.cfg.fileInput.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Primefaces show case there is [FileUpload example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSkinning.jsf), which is looks like what you are asking for:

```
<p:fileUpload widgetVar="uploader" height="48" width="48"  
    fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"  
    image="/images/browse.png" cancelImage="/images/cancel.png"  
    allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;" description="Images" customUI="true"/>  

<h:outputLink value="#" title="Upload" onclick="uploader.upload();"   
    style="font-weight:bold;color:#616D7E">  
    Upload Files  
</h:outputLink>
```

It's implemented in flash. I don't know, if there are html5 alternatives.
You may also try autoupload attribute(`auto="true"`) instead of using link.
Please, let me know, if you get it working.

Comment: are you able to use javascript api for primefaces 3.0.M4 ?  I'm struggling with this for a while.